# Include graphics in new acronym command

Tags: graphics, glossaries, acronyms

I want to include an image in my `List of Abbreviations`. So far I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx} % images
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym, nonumberlist, nopostdot, shortcuts, style=tree]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{alttree}
\glssetwidest{}
\glssetwidest[1]{loooooongest}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations} 
\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{}
\newglossaryentry{software}{name={{Computer Software and Languages}}, description={\nopostdesc}, sort={Computer}}
\glsenablehyper
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[parent=software, sort={smurf}]{smurf}{\textsc{Smurf}}{Sub-Millimetre User Reduction Facility}

\begin{document}

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title={List of Abbreviations}]
    \mbox{}\\
    Some reference to \acs{smurf}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

However, I want to include a figure in the list of abbreviations so I use the replace the `newacronym` command with:

```
\newacronym[parent=software, sort={smurf}]{smurf}{\textsc{Smurf}}{Sub-Millimetre User Reduction Facility (\includegraphics{./figs/smurf_400x400.eps})}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@
                              ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
l.18 ...ncludegraphics{./figs/smurf_400x400.eps})}

?
```

Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `\protect\includegraphics`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\includegraphics` is a fragile command and needs to be protected when used in any of [the glossary fields that expand](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion) (`long` in this case).

```
\newacronym[parent=software, sort={smurf}]{smurf}{\textsc{Smurf}}
{Sub-Millimetre User Reduction Facility 
(\protect\includegraphics{./figs/smurf_400x400.eps})}
```